# How do I wire a relay board into existing series recepticles

Tags: relay, ground, wiring, mains

I have a four channel relay, that I'm going to attempt to wire into a terminal block. I have experience with mains wiring and some experience with electronics, but no experience wiring relays. Basically I have a number of receptacles that are wired in series. I would like to rewire them so that the relays can switch each one on and off. I'm assuming that it would break one of the wires with the relay, but I'm confused about what to do with the other wire. or the other terminal. Can I break just one side of the circuit? and leave the other side connected in series? or is there some inherent danger in that. Attached is a photo of the receptacles, and the relay.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you really sure the receptacles are wired in series?  If so, you have something very strange.  You really need to show a diagram.  All the hand waving leaves a lot of questions.

Comment: here are links to those images http://i.imgur.com/nvioXrw.jpg

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IE9TIjA.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The second picture shows the outlets wired in parallel, not series.

A relay is basically a electrically-controlled switch.  To turn off a normal outlet, all you have to do is interrupt the hot line, which black in your picture.  Disconnect the existing black wires and have a single black wire going to each socket.  Each of these black wires goes to one contact of the relay, and the master black connection to the opposite contacts of the relays.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sure your more knowlegeable than I am but I think they are wired in series ... It's the inside of a surge protector, if you look closely at the wires, they are jumpers from one socket to another. I think I understand what your saying though. In order to function, I need to wire them in parallel, with the feed wire coming from the relay (the third terminal) and then feed the live line to the second terminal. My question is then, what is the first terminal of the relay?

Comment: Actually, I think I get it, one side is the closed, and one side is open, so the power wire goes to the center of the relay, and then the output goes on one side of the other depending on if I want the relay on or off when energized.

Comment: @user: Perhaps what you are missing is that the clump of 4 holes labeled "white" on each outlet are all connected inside the outlet.  That is why they may look wired in series, but are really wired in parallel.

Comment: @ Olin Lathrop Your absolutely right (I'm sure you knew that though), My brain was looking at it all wrong, because the circuits were in sequence, I kept thinking they were in series .... got it working with the relays